# Perl -e file test doesn't recognize dead links

Tags: perl

I have a script which creates a new directory and then goes over all the content of a different (the source) directory and creates links in the new directory to each element in the source directory. The relevant part of the script is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Cwd 'getcwd';
use Cwd 'realpath';
#...
opendir ($LC, $source_dir) or die "Cannot open directory: '$source_dir': $!";

while ($entry = readdir $LC) {
    next if $entry =~ /\A\.\.?\z/;
    print "-I- Creating a link $entry\n";
    system "ln -s ".realpath("${source_dir}/${entry}")." ${new_dir}/$entry";
    die "-E- couldn't create link ${new_dir}/$entry ... exiting.\n" unless -e "${new_dir}/$entry";
}

closedir $LC;
#...
```

The problem arises when one of the files in the source directory is a dead link. The command `ln` creates a file called `/new_dir/dead_link` in the new directory and it links to `/source_dir/deal_link`, but because `/source_dir/deal_link` links to a non existing file, the `-e` command recognizes `/source_dir/deal_link` as not existing and calls the `die` command.

Running `ls -ltr /new_dir/dead link` gives:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user ttt 44 Dec  7 07:40 /new_dir/dead_link -> /source_dir/dead_link
```

How can I do that `-e` will only check if the file exists, regardless of where it links to?

Comment: Then why does it say that the file doesn't exist, while ls says is exists?

Comment: @mpapec, see edit. Also, adding the line `next unless (-e "${source_dir}/${entry}");` causes the loop to jump over the dead link and not try to copy it (which is not what I need, I need the directories to be identical).

Comment: if you don't care whether is dead/alive link or file then `if (-e "file" or -l "file")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count a symbolic link as "existing" if present, regardless of whether or not the file it points to also exists, you can do this:

```
(-e "$newdir/$entry" || -l "$newdir/$entry")
```

The `-l` test returns true if the named file is a symlink, and doesn't care where it links.  But it returns false for anything that's not a symlink, so you still need the `-e` to handle other types of files.

Comment: There's no need for `-e`. Just `-l` will return *false* if the name doesn't exist

Comment: @Borodin: but it will also return false if it isn't a link

Comment: @ysth: But he *knows* it's a link as he just created it. In fact if the `ln -s` failed because there was already a node by that name then he *doesn't* want a true value.